# jquery sortable with style crash on IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have ordered listed pictures that is jquery sortable.
When i move the 1st picture to 2nd position, it either
1. crashes
2. the 1st 2 pictures disappear and i need to select all to make those picture re-drawn.

http://jsbin.com/alekom/edit#javascript,html

How do i fix both 1 and 2 above?

Note this happens only with float: left style and on IE9.
To repro this, you may need to move 1st item to 2nd several times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe that's a bug in jQuery UI.
Because you set the "CSS" to float:left, the UI struggles to re-position the "sortable" items and crashes IE9. Very cool.